# Checkbox with Array inside looping False Result?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have checkbox inside looping like this.

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<$jumlah;$i++)  {

     echo "<tr>
          <td align='center'><input type='text' name='PROSES[]' placeholder='Input Proses $i'/></td>
          <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='NOTIF[]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='REMINDER[]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='DECISION[]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='AUTHOR[]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'><input type='text' name='SIAPA[]' size='40' placeholder='dari siap ke siapa' /></td>
      </tr>";


}//end for

echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

and the query to input like this

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) {
  $proses = $_POST[PROSES];//value from selectbox
  $jumlah = count($proses);

$max_id = $data_max_id[ID];

        for($i=0;$i<$jumlah;$i++) {

            $query_input = "INSERT INTO data_proses SET ID_input       = '$max_id',
                                                        proses         = '$proses[$i]',
                                                        notifikasi     = '$notif[$i]',
                                                        reminder       = '$reminder[$i]',
                                                        decision       = '$decision[$i]',
                                                        authorization  = '$author[$i]',
                                                        dari_siapa     = '$siapa[$i]'";

            $hasil_input = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_input);                                                     
        }//end for
}
```

it will Produce table like this

[image]

In Short,

After I have  submit to mysql is successfull But stil wrong. IF I have Check like that image the database have wrong result like this

[image]

```
input :
        [x][x][ ][ ]
        [ ][x][x][ ]
        [ ][ ][x][x]

On database : 

        [x][x][x][x]
        [ ][x][x][ ]
        [ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Can anyone help to fix my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It'd be best if you show the code that inserts/saves to the database.

Comment: When you submit checkboxes, only the checked ones are submitted. You need to give them values that tell you which row the checkbox is onl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the row number in the names of all the checkboxes. Only the checked boxes get submitted, and PHP will index them all from `0` if they don't have an explicit index -- you won't see empty values for the checkboxes that are skipped.

```
for($i=0;$i<$jumlah;$i++)  {

     echo "<tr>
          <td align='center'><input type='text' name='PROSES[]' placeholder='Input Proses $i'/></td>
          <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='NOTIF[$i]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='REMINDER[$i]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='DECISION[$i]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='AUTHOR[$i]'  value='Yes'/></td>
          <td align='center'><input type='text' name='SIAPA[]' size='40' placeholder='dari siap ke siapa' /></td>
      </tr>";


}//end for
```